# how to query for range of data and info from multiple tables SQL?

Tags: sql, range

I've got two tables--one for Jobs and another for Connections.  One job can have many connections.  Connetion's PKs are connid + timestamp, it has a foreign key (JOBID) pointing to Job's JOBID.

```
JOBID  | NAME
-------+-------
  id1  | Name of Job 1
  id2  | Job 2's Name

CONNID | TIMESTAMP | JOBID | AMOUNT
-------+-------+--------+----------
012    |  doesn't  |  id1  | 11
012    |  matter   |  id1  | 15
012    |           |  id1  | 20
012    |           |  id1  | 30
020    |           |  id1  | 2
020    |           |  id1  | 5
549    |           |  id2  | 19
549    |           |  id2  | 30
549    |           |  id2  | 50
549    |           |  id2  | 57
549    |           |  id2  | 60
```

So what I want to do is, from the connection table, get the total of the range for each connection for each job.  So for job-id1 I want (30-11)+(5-2) which is 22 and for job-id2 I want (60-19) which is 41.  Now I can figure out how to do the max minus the min for each connection...

```
SELECT 
   CONNID ,
   MAX(AMOUNT) - MIN(AMOUNT) AS range
FROM Connection 
GROUP BY CONNID
```

...but I'm not familiar enough with sql to figure out what more I need (as in I took a single database class years ago in college).  In addition to that, I want it sorted by the job's name which I'm sure adds a whole 'nother layer of complication since I have to get that from the Job table.

Basically, I want the result set to look like

```
NAME          | range
--------------+------
Name of Job 1 |  22
Job 2's Name  |  41
```

In the end, I'll want to be able to do this for only the last 24 hours, but that should only be adding a WHERE clause in there which should be pretty straight forward.

The answer I'm hoping for will contain a query for both just a query of the Connection table with a JOBID (so not worried about the job's name for the first part of the answer) and then the query that I'm actually looking for that gives me the result set above, so that I can explicitly see the extra step needed to get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thinking is along the right track, you just need to go further.

The first group by needs to be by connection and job.  This gets you the individual ranges for each job.  Then you want to group these together at the connection level.  You can do this with a subquery:

```
select connid, SUM(range) as range
from (SELECT CONNID, jobid, MAX(AMOUNT) - MIN(AMOUNT) AS range
      FROM Connection 
      GROUP BY CONNID, jobid
     ) cj
group by connid
```

If you want the total time for a job and to sort by the *job* name, then try something like:

```
select jobname, SUM(range) as range
from (SELECT CONNID, jobid, MAX(AMOUNT) - MIN(AMOUNT) AS range
      FROM Connection 
      GROUP BY CONNID, jobid
     ) cj join
     job j
     on j.jobid = cj.jobid
group by jobname
```

This sums up the job *within* a connection to get the range and then adds that up.

Comment: Looks like we posted the same answer, so it must be right ;)  Just a heads up that the final grouping he wants is by JOBID not by CONNID.  So your last GROUP ON should be switched to `group by jobid` I think.  OP: if you agree, then you can accept this answer as he posted it before me.

Comment: @EliGassert . . . The text of the question strongly suggests the answer should be in terms of connections.  I do admit that the sample results suggest by job, but I'll go with connection.

Comment: Are you sure? *So for job-id1 I want (30-11)+(5-2) which is 22 and for job-id2 I want (60-19) which is 41.*  I read that as he wants his results to be in the form `jobid|time`

Comment: To clarify, most of the data is in Connections, but I want it sorted by the Job Name field, which is in the Jobs table.

Answer (score 1):

You're close.  It's a two-stop process:

1. Get the max/min for each CONNID+JOBID
2. Then get the sum of the min/max for each CONNID+JOBID for each JOBID

So step 1:

```
SELECT 
   CONNID, JOBID
   MAX(AMOUNT) - MIN(AMOUNT) AS Range1
FROM Connection 
GROUP BY CONNID, JOBID
```

Then step 2 is taking the resutls of step 1 and further aggregating it

```
SELECT JOBID, SUM([Range]) AS [Range]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
       CONNID, JOBID
       MAX(AMOUNT) - MIN(AMOUNT) AS [Range]
    FROM Connection 
    GROUP BY CONNID, JOBID
) AS t0
GROUP BY JOBID
```

Comment: Good answer and still helpful.  I chose Gordon's, though, because I was wanting them grouped by job name.

Comment: Sounds good. I was debating with Gordon in his comment as to how you wanted it grouped.  I guess I was wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to break it apart for understanding, I use a temp table to subtotal

```
    SELECT 
       JOBID
       , CONNID 
       , MAX(AMOUNT) - MIN(AMOUNT) AS range
       into #subtotal
    FROM Connection 
    --Where timestamp between "low" and "high"
    GROUP BY JOBID, CONNID 

    select * from #subtotal

    Select job.Name
           , sum(range) as range 
    from #subtotal inner join job on job.jobid = #subtotal.jobid 
    group by job.Name

    drop table #subtotal
```